# Python Multiprocessing Duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

When I run this script on Linux, it prints 8 duplicates. How to force python use all cores on different results, rather than on duplicates?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f():
    f = open("/path/to/10.txt", 'r')
    l = [s.strip('\n') for s in f]
    f.close()

    for a in range(0, len(l)):
        for b in range(0, len(l)):
            result = 0
            if (a == b):
                result = 1
            else:
                counter = 0
                for i in range(len(l[a])):
                    if (int(l[a][i]) == int(l[b][i]) == 1):
                        counter += 1
                    result = counter / 10000   
                    print((a + 1), (b + 1), result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to run more than one core you will have to use multiple processes, here you are just using one.

also you need to break your routine `f` in independent units/routine such a way that it can work in parallel and the whole task can be shared among the multiple worker processes.

Here is a sample 2-process code, which can use multiple cores on your machine:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def task(arg):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__'
    value = 'something'
    prc1 = Process(target=task, args=(value,))
    prc2 = Process(target=task, args=(value,))
    prc1.start()
    prc2.start()
    prc1.join()
    prc2.join()
```

Comment: If am still getting 8 duplicates. Can not I use just `prc1 = Process(target=task)`

Comment: please explain what do you mean by `duplicates`? further if you use a single `Process` you will be able to use only one core of your machine.

Comment: gettings results like `1 2 0.0001
1 2 0.0002
1 2 0.0002
1 2 0.0002` instead of just one line `1 2 0.0001`. And why I get different results for the same comparison?